# take a array value from and array object with destructuring javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have an array of objects below:

```
const obj = [
 0:{
  "content": {
    "tabs": [
      {
        "name": "Overview",
        "id": 1,      
        "sections":[           
          {"event_description":"Event Description"},
          {"photos":"Photos"},
          {"reference_documents":"Reference Documents"},
          {"discussion":"Discussion"}

        ]
      },{...},{..}
     ]
   }
 },
 1:{}
]
```

How can I take just the `sections` array from obj with destructuring?
I've tried these things:

```
const [{content={}}] = obj;
const [{content{tabs={}}]=obj;
const [{content{tabs[0]{sections}}}]=obj;
```

And also `sections` should be changed to another variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could destructure the object with a proper index as key and take a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

If necessary add some default values.

```js
const
    obj = [{ content: { tabs: [{ name: "Overview", id: 1, sections: [{ event_description: "Event Description" }, { photos: "Photos" }, { reference_documents: "Reference Documents" }, { discussion: "Discussion" }] }] } }],
    key = 'sections',
    { 0: { content: { tabs: { 0: { [key]: value } } } } }= obj;

console.log(value);
```

Comment: example changed a little

Comment: **const [ { content: { tabs: { 0: { sections:foo = [] } = {} } = {} } = {} } ] = obj;** worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

basically you are really close, here you have a working example, and also adding default values just in case :)

```js
const obj = {
  content: {
    tabs: [{
      name: "Overview",
      id: 1,
      sections: [{
        event_description: "Event Description"
      }, {
        photos: "Photos"
      }, {
        reference_documents: "Reference Documents"
      }, {
        discussion: "Discussion"
      }]
    }]
  }
};

const { content: { tabs: { 0: { sections = [] } = {} } = {} } = {} } = obj;

console.log(sections);
```

Comment: **const [ { content: { tabs: { 0: { sections:foo = [] } = {} } = {} } = {} } ] = obj;**    worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure down to the `tabs` array using `[]`, and take the first object's `section` property from that array like so:

```js
const obj = [{ "content": { "tabs": [{ "name": "Overview", "id": 1, "sections": [{ "event_description": "Event Description" }, { "photos": "Photos" }, { "reference_documents": "Reference Documents" }, { "discussion": "Discussion" } ] }] } }];

const [{content: {tabs: [{sections: foo}]}}] = obj;
console.log(foo); // here `foo` refers to sections
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

Destructuring syntax mimics the object literal syntax and so, it might be easier to understand when formatted. Here is a side-by-side comparison of the destructuring syntax and the array of objects you have:

```
// Desctructuing:       Actual object/array:
const [{                // [{
  content: {            //   "content": {             
    tabs: [{            //     "tabs": [{
      sections: foo     //       "name": "Overview", "id": 1, "sections": {...}
    }]                  //     }, ...]
  }                     //   }
}] = obj;               // }, ...]
```

Comment: sorry, example changed a little

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```js
const obj ={
  "content": {
    "tabs": [
      {
        "name": "Overview",
        "id": 1,      
        "sections":[           
          {"event_description":"Event Description"},
          {"photos":"Photos"},
          {"reference_documents":"Reference Documents"},
          {"discussion":"Discussion"}

        ]
      }
     ]
   }
};

const { content: { tabs } } = obj;

const sections = tabs.map(tab => tab.sections)

console.log(sections)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by going in one at a time or using the keys to destruture.

```
const obj ={
  "content": {
    "tabs": [
      {
        "name": "Overview",
        "id": 1,      
        "sections":[           
          {"event_description":"Event Description"},
          {"photos":"Photos"},
          {"reference_documents":"Reference Documents"},
          {"discussion":"Discussion"}

        ]
      },
     ]


  }
}
//do the following
const {content} = obj;
const {tabs} = obj["content"} //or const {tabs} = content
```

similarly all throughout.